# how to track swaps through affiliateAddress or feeRecipient that are done through 0x api?

Tags: 0x, swaps, trading

I found in the documentation that affiliateAddress can be used to track swaps that are sent to the 0x api, but how to filter this data based on affiliateAddress, I haven't found any way to track the swaps that are sent to our interface through 0x api, we are using 0x api on Ethereum, Polygon and BSC, so we want to track the trades on these networks

[image: affiliateAddress]

Answer (score 0):

We don't emit this data as events off of the contract as it is expensive for the user. The data is attached to the calldata of the transaction instead.

You should be able to search it on 0xTracker (more network support coming)

https://0xtracker.com/search?q=AFFILIATE_ADDRESS